# Getting invalid column name in SQL/Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

I will preface this by saying I am nowhere near being an expert in SQL. Using Excel I am trying to use one specific cell as the input to query, but I run into a problem where a column I created isn't defined as a column. Please help.

```
 SELECT
CASE  
WHEN CHARINDEX(',', TCPIPADDRESS) > 0 THEN LEFT(TCPIPADDRESS, CHARINDEX(',', TCPIPADDRESS) - 1) ELSE TCPIPADDRESS END AS IPADDRESS,   
ADMachine.ADMachineName, ADMachine.SerialNumber, 
ADMachine.OperatingSystem, ADUsers.ADUser, ADUsers.ADDisplayName, employee_data.employee_first_name, 
employee_data.employee_last_name, asset_center.LOCATION_SITENAME, asset_center.TCPIPHOSTNAME, 
asset_center.MAC_ADDRESS, ADUsers.ADUserOU
FROM PC_GAP.dbo.ADMachine ADMachine, PC_GAP.dbo.ADUsers ADUsers, PC_GAP.dbo.asset_center asset_center, PC_GAP.dbo.employee_data employee_data
WHERE ADUsers.ADUser = employee_data.employee_user_name AND ADMachine.SerialNumber = asset_center.SERIALNO AND ADUsers.ADUser = asset_center.LAST_LOGGED_ON_USER
```

The IPAddress at the end is where the problem lies.

Edit 1: Added the additional information from the SQL statement to paint the whole picture (originally left out irrelevant data)

Comment: What problem are you running into? What is the error you are getting? A little bit more of the specifics would help

Comment: I have this code entered in excel/microsoft query. When I add the last bit [AND ((IPAddress=?))] to allow me to set the parameters for a cell to act as the "?" I get an error that says invalid column name.

Answer (score 3):

Alright so first off you need to stop using the old style joins for all of the reasons listed [here](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

You are also going to run into an issue that you aren't joining on anything other than one of your tables. I'm pretty sure this will not give you the results that you are looking for.

Then finally you need to think about the order of [operations](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-sql-query-order-of-operations.htm). Since the `WHERE` clause is evaluated before the the select you cannot refer to your alias in the where clause. You can only reference an alias with an `ORDER BY` or by using a subquery or a cte.

You can however use your case expression in your `where` clause. The example would be as follows.

```
CASE
  WHEN CHARINDEX(',', TCPIPADDRESS) > 0 
  THEN LEFT(TCPIPADDRESS, CHARINDEX(',', TCPIPADDRESS) - 1) 
  ELSE TCPIPADDRESS 
END = ?
```

As stated previously you could also turn this entire thing into a subquery. I would use your code as an example for that but I'm not entirely sure what exactly you're hoping to accomplish with your current set of joins so my example will be a bit generic.

```
select
    GenericColumn
    (select
        blah as Pity,
        GenericColumn
    from dbo.TheFoo)
where Pity = SeachCondition
```

Comment: We were basically trying to make it where you could enter an IP address and see who owned that machine and some of the information behind it. Unfortunately we do not own any of the data and the groups that do have taken horrible care of it. The IP address field sometimes has just an IPv4 address and sometimes has both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses separated by a comma. We wanted to search just on the IPv4.

Comment: Yes but the way you're defining your joins are going to give you a cartesian product.

Comment: You could also throw in some sugar to replace the CASE expression with a possibly shorter one: `ISNULL(LEFT(TCPIPADDRESS,  NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', TCPIPADDRESS), 0) - 1), TCPIPADDRESS)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a column alias in the WHERE clause.  You have to use the whole formula that you aliased.

```
WHERE ADMachine.SerialNumber = asset_center.SERIALNO AND ((CASE  
WHEN CHARINDEX(',', TCPIPADDRESS) > 0 THEN LEFT(TCPIPADDRESS, CHARINDEX(',', TCPIPADDRESS) - 1) ELSE TCPIPADDRESS END=?))
```

To illustrate Aaron's suggestion, it would look more like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT    
CASE  
  WHEN CHARINDEX(',', TCPIPADDRESS) > 0 THEN LEFT(TCPIPADDRESS, CHARINDEX(',', TCPIPADDRESS) - 1) ELSE TCPIPADDRESS END AS IPADDRESS,   
ADMachine.ADMachineName,  
ADMachine.OperatingSystem,
asset_center.MAC_ADDRESS,

FROM PC_GAP.dbo.ADMachine ADMachine, PC_GAP.dbo.ADUsers ADUsers, PC_GAP.dbo.asset_center asset_center, PC_GAP.dbo.employee_data employee_data
)
  SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE ADMachine.SerialNumber = asset_center.SERIALNO AND ((IPAddress=?))
```

Comment: will this allow me to use a cell as the sort/filter criteria though?

Comment: Or an easier way would be to derive the expression in a CTE, subquery, derived table, etc. Then the outer query can use the alias in any clause.

Comment: @MilesCurtis well that I don't know because I'm not an Excel expert.   I just know that this will fix your SQL syntax problem.   You could also try Aaron's suggestion to see if either or both of them work for your Excel purposes.

Comment: I will give that a shot and report back!

Comment: When I try this the entire where part lists as not being able to be bound

Comment: This might be a little further than you wanted to go, but it should work:   make a view out of this query on your sql server, and then do a straight SELECT on the view from Excel.   That should get all the Excel limitations out of the way.   You can leave the WHERE clause out of the view and implement that from Excel to allow for the "?".